# Не могу циклом пройтись по словарю

Tags: python-3.x

```
geo_logs = [
    {'visit1': ['Москва', 'Россия']},
    {'visit2': ['Дели', 'Индия']},
    {'visit3': ['Владимир', 'Россия']},
    {'visit4': ['Лиссабон', 'Португалия']},
    {'visit5': ['Париж', 'Франция']},
    {'visit6': ['Лиссабон', 'Португалия']},
    {'visit7': ['Тула', 'Россия']},
    {'visit8': ['Тула', 'Россия']},
    {'visit9': ['Курск', 'Россия']},
   {'visit10': ['Архангельск', 'Россия']}
]

for i in geo_logs:

  for j in i:

    if 'Россия' in j:
      print(j)
```

Я пробую обходить вложенным циклом словарь, но он почему то обходит только ключи, а значения как-будто игнорирует, в итоге if не выполняется. А мне нужно обойти значения этих ключей и где есть Россия вывести в консоль. Прошу более полного объяснения, потому что я новичок

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: `for j in i.values():`